# How to remove quotes around numbers to a JSON stringify object?

Tags: javascript, json, regex

I need to remove the double quotes between the numbers in my json object previously stringify.

Here is the initial one :

```
[ { "coucou": "Tolu",  "salut": "55",   "tata": "NORMAL", "loulou": "Tolu", "tutu": "NORMAL", "toto": "Tolu", "Baba": "24"   } 
, { "coucou": "TRUE",  "salut": "128",  "tata": "LOW",    "loulou": "Tolu", "tutu": "LOW",    "toto": "TRUE", "Baba": "7"    } 
, { "coucou": "Salut", "salut": "15.7", "tata": "LOW",    "loulou": "Toli", "tutu": "NORMAL", "toto": "toti", "Baba": "-5"   } 
, { "coucou": "Salut", "salut": "-148", "tata": "LOW",    "loulou": "Toli", "tutu": "NORMAL", "toto": "toti", "Baba": "-578" } 
]
```

The regex that I use for that is :

```
const regex2 = /"-?([0-9]+\.{0,1}[0-9]*)"/g 
json = json.replace(regex2, '$1')
```

```js
let json = 
`[ { "coucou": "Tolu",  "salut": "55",   "tata": "NORMAL", "loulou": "Tolu", "tutu": "NORMAL", "toto": "Tolu", "Baba": "24"   } 
 , { "coucou": "TRUE",  "salut": "128",  "tata": "LOW",    "loulou": "Tolu", "tutu": "LOW",    "toto": "TRUE", "Baba": "7"    } 
 , { "coucou": "Salut", "salut": "15.7", "tata": "LOW",    "loulou": "Toli", "tutu": "NORMAL", "toto": "toti", "Baba": "-5"   } 
 , { "coucou": "Salut", "salut": "-148", "tata": "LOW",    "loulou": "Toli", "tutu": "NORMAL", "toto": "toti", "Baba": "-578" } 
 ]`

const regex2 = /"-?([0-9]+\.{0,1}[0-9]*)"/g 
json = json.replace(regex2, '$1')

console.log( json)
```

But the result I get is that is also removes the negative operators so it changes all the results I want for my application :

```
[ { "X0": "Tolu",  "X1": 55,   "X2": "NORMAL", "X3": "Tolu", "X4": "NORMAL", "X5": "Tolu", "X6": 24  } 
, { "X0": "TRUE",  "X1": 128,  "X2": "LOW",    "X3": "Tolu", "X4": "LOW",    "X5": "TRUE", "X6": 7   } 
, { "X0": "Salut", "X1": 15.7, "X2": "LOW",    "X3": "Toli", "X4": "NORMAL", "X5": "toti", "X6": 5   } 
, { "X0": "Salut", "X1": 148,  "X2": "LOW",    "X3": "Toli", "X4": "NORMAL", "X5": "toti", "X6": 578 } 
]
```

Does anybody know how to conserve the operators while removing double quotations marks around numbers with a regex ?

Comment: So why don't you include `-?` into Group 1? `const regex2 = /"(-?\d*\.?\d+)"/g`

Comment: You should not do this with regex. You should solve this *before* stringifying.

Comment: but `"coucou"` is not changed to `"X0"`....

Answer (score 1):

```js
let json = 
`[ { "coucou": "Tolu",  "salut": "55",   "tata": "NORMAL", "loulou": "Tolu", "tutu": "NORMAL", "toto": "Tolu", "Baba": "24"   } 
 , { "coucou": "TRUE",  "salut": "128",  "tata": "LOW",    "loulou": "Tolu", "tutu": "LOW",    "toto": "TRUE", "Baba": "7"    } 
 , { "coucou": "Salut", "salut": "15.7", "tata": "LOW",    "loulou": "Toli", "tutu": "NORMAL", "toto": "toti", "Baba": "-5"   } 
 , { "coucou": "Salut", "salut": "-148", "tata": "LOW",    "loulou": "Toli", "tutu": "NORMAL", "toto": "toti", "Baba": "-578" } 
 ]`

const regex = /"(-|)([0-9]+(?:\.[0-9]+)?)"/g 
json = json.replace(regex, '$1$2')

console.log(json)
```

Answer (score 0):

for array of objects you can use the below code.

pass the Object to this function, it will return the updated object with all the values preserved.

```
function updateJson(objects) {
    for (var i = 0; i < objects.length; i++) {
        var obj = objects[i];
        for (var prop in obj) {
            if (obj.hasOwnProperty(prop) && obj[prop] !== null && !isNaN(obj[prop])) {
                obj[prop] = +obj[prop];
            }
        }
    }
    return obj;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your original code should work with

```
const regex2 = /"(-?[0-9]+\.{0,1}[0-9]*)"/g 
json = json.replace(regex2, '$1')
```